# rails/rspec: Fabricator - testing associations (ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rspec, fabricator

I am writing tests for my models and came across an error I can't seem to resolve. I'm using rspec and Fabricator. Things work fine when being tested in isolation but when I try to test for associations I get an ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError.

**models/user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  validates :email, uniqueness: true, presence: true
  belongs_to :company, required: false
end
```

**models/company.rb**

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  validates :organisation_number, uniqueness: true, presence: true
  has_many :users, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**schema**

```
create_table "companies", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "organisation_number"
  ...
end

create_table "users", id: :serial, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    ...
    t.bigint "company_id"
    t.index ["company_id"], name: "index_users_on_company_id"
    ...
  end
```

**fabricators/user_fabricator.rb**

```
Fabricator :user do
  email { Faker::Internet.email }
  password '123456'
  confirmed_at Time.now
end
```

**fabricators/company_fabricator.rb**

```
Fabricator :company do
  organisation_number { Faker::Company.swedish_organisation_number }
end
```

**spec/user_spec.rb** (first test passes, the second fails)

```
describe User do
  context '#create' do
    it 'Creates a user when correct email and password provided' do
      user = Fabricate(:user)
      expect(user).to be_valid
    end
    it 'Lets assign a company to user' do
      company = Fabricate(:company)
      expect(Fabricate.build :user, company: company).to be_valid
    end
  end
end
```

I also tried adding a company straight to the User fabricator, like so (which seems to me like a correct implementation of the [documentation](https://www.fabricationgem.org/)):

```
Fabricator :user do
  email { Faker::Internet.email }
  password '123456'
  confirmed_at Time.now
  company
end
```

and the other way around, adding users to the Company fabricator, like so:

```
Fabricator :company do
  organisation_number { Faker::Company.swedish_organisation_number }
  users(count: 3) { Fabricate(:user) }
end
```

but both approaches left me with the same error:

User#create Lets assign a company to user 
Failure/Error: company = Fabricate(:company)
ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute 'company_id'

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does your user table have a `company_id` column because the error suggests it does not

Comment: @engineersmnky yeah, it does. sorry, forgot to add schema (updated question now)

Comment: Are you sure that your test database includes that column again because the error is stating that `company_id` is not an attribute of `User`. Make sure that the spec_helper file includes this line `ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!` or try running `RAILS_ENV=test rake db:migrate`

Comment: Great! This did it. If you could explain a bit more what this line does and how come my databases were not synched, I'd happily mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write up my own answer but I am not sure that I could describe it better than `RSpec` already has so this is taken directly from [Here](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/upgrade):

> **Rails 4.x `ActiveRecord::Migration` pending migration checks**
>
> If you are not using `ActiveRecord` you do not need to worry about these
>   settings.
>
> Users of Rails 4.x can now take advantage of improved schema migration and sync abilities. Prior to RSpec 3, users were required to manually run migrations in both the development and test environments. Additionally, the behavior differed depending on if the specs were run via `rake` or via the standalone `rspec` command.
>
> With the release of Rails 4, new APIs have been exposed on
>   `ActiveRecord::Migration`. This allows RSpec to take advantage of these new
>   standard migration checks, mirroring behavior across the board.
>
> - Rails 4.0.x
>
>   Add the following to the top of the `rails_helper` file after Rails has
>     been required:
>
>   ```
>    ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending!
>   ```
>
>   This will raise an exception if there are any pending schema changes. Users will still be required to manually keep the development and test environments in sync.
> - Rails 4.1+
>
>   With this release there was an exciting new feature. Users no longer need to keep the development and test environments in sync. To take advantage of this add the following to the top of the `rails_helper` file after Rails has been required:
>
>   ```
>    ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!
>   ```
>
>   What this does is that rather than just raising when the test schema has
>     pending migrations, Rails will try to load the schema. An exception will
>     now only be raised if there are pending migrations afterwards the schema
>     has been loaded.
>
>   There are a few caveates to be aware of when using this:
>
>   - Migrations still need to be run manually; although now this only has to be done in the 'development' environment
>   - An exception will be raised If the schema has not been initialized. The exception will provide instructions stating `rake db:migrate` needs to be run.
>
> It is possible to opt-out of checking for pending migrations. Since this is
>   actually a feature of Rails, the change needs to be done as part of the Rails
>   configuration. To do this, add the following to your `config/environments/test.rb` file:
>
> ```
> config.active_record.maintain_test_schema = false
> ```
>
> New RSpec projects don't need to worry about these commands as the `rails generate rspec:install` will add them automatically.